# Prevent React Native packager from trying to resolve certain modules

Tags: javascript, browserify, react-native

I'm trying to use Browserify for my React Native project. The idea is that I first bundle my sources together with Browserify, marking 'react-native' as an external module, and then use the React Native packager to bundle my bundle with React Native and serve it. It works, but the packager keeps printing errors for my modules:

```
Unable to resolve module ../../myModule from index.ios.js
```

Is there a way to tell the packager to ignore these modules?

**EDIT** An example of my setup:

*./src/ImportantModule.js:*

```
module.exports = function() { return "Text"; }
```

*./src/ImportantComponent.js:*

```
var React = require('react-native');
var M     = require('./ImportantModule');

var MyApp = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        var text = M();
        return React.createElement(React.Text, null, text);
    }
});

React.AppRegistry.registerComponent('test', function () { return MyApp; });
```

Then run in the project folder:

```
browserify ./src/ImportantComponent.js --exclude react-native > ./index.ios.js
```

It works, but the packager complains:

```
Unable to resolve module ./ImportantModule from /Users/.../index.ios.js
```

The only reason I need Browserify is that I want to use aliasify for path aliases. Is there a way to do that with the React Native Packager? If not, is there a way to hide these "errors"?

Answer (score -3):

The way I work with React-native is to just assume it's a subset of node. React-native doesn't use NodeJS or Google's V8.

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot see how this is relevant to my question. Could you explain?

Comment: can you give us more example of your code and the tree of the directory?

Comment: sorry for the delay, I've just added an example.